# Error con listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Hola a todos y muchas gracias de antemano. Dispongo del siguiente código, el cuál modifica la lista eliminando todas las ocurrencias del número pasado como segundo parámetro.

```
import number_functions

numbers = [12, 10, 23, 10, 10, 45, 10]
value = 10
number_functions.delete_value(numbers, value)
print(numbers)



def delete_value(numbers, value):
    for i in numbers:
        numbers.remove(value)

    return numbers
```

SE PRODUCE UN ERROR PARA ALGUNOS CASOS. EL ERROR ES EL SIGUIENTE:

> list.remove(x): x not in list

```
input: [ 1, -1, 0, 7, -4], 0
output: list.remove(x): x not in list

input: [12, 10, 23, 10, 10, 45, 10], 10
output: [12, 23, 45]
```

Comment: Aparte de que no debes eliminar elementos de una lista mientras iteras por ella, estás eliminando el elemento `valor` más veces de las que aparece. Al hacer `for i in numbers` estás iterando tantas veces como elementos haya en la lista. En tu caso la lista tiene 7 elementos, luego iteras 7 veces. En cada una de esas iteraciones haces `remove(value)`, así que estás intentando eliminar el 10 siete veces, y no está tantas veces.

Answer (score 0):

No debes editar una lista la cual estas haciendo un `for` ya que esta podria saltar elementos de la lista, podrias cambiar el codigo para que retorne una nueva lista ya modificada utilizando un `lambda` (o cualquier otro forma).

Ejemplo:

```py
def delete_value(numbers, value):
    return [number for number in numbers if number != value]
```

al final tu codigo quedaria asi

```py
import number_functions

numbers = [12, 10, 23, 10, 10, 45, 10]
value = 10
numbers = number_functions.delete_value(numbers, value)
print(numbers)
```

Si por alguna razon necesitas modificar el `array` que pasas por parametro entonces podrias modificar solo la funcion `delete_value` con el siguiente codigo:

```py
def delete_value(numbers, value):
    for i in reversed(range(0,len(numbers))):
        numVal = numbers[i]
        if(numbers[i] == value):
            del numbers[i]
    return numbers;
```

Nota: la funcion remove elimina el primer elemento que coincidan, si el elemento no existe entonces lanza un error.

En tu caso el error ocurre por que estas eliminando el elemento por cada iteración de cada numero de la lista, como dije anteriormente si eliminar valores en una lista que le estas haciendo un `for` vas a saltar valores. Ahora tu pregunta seria, por que para una `array` funciona y para otro no?, es que el primer `array` tienes 3 valores repetidos de 10 y un tamano de 7 elementos ya cuando eliminas los 3 primeros la lista termina de iterar y por eso no da error, sin embargo en el segundo `array` tienes un solo 0 y 5 numeros, por eso en la segunda iteracion lanza el error ya que el 0 no existe en la lista.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda Roberto me has ayudado bastante